# XlworkBook Set color with Hexcode

Tags: excel, closedxml

```
if (total == 100) {
    ws1.Range("A"+ counterC2+":M" + counterC2).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.BabyPink;
}
else {
    ws1.Range("A" + counterC2 + ":M" + counterC2).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Aqua;
}
```

code look like this but i have directly mentioned color name but I need to use hex code. please share syntax or sample code

Comment: I do not have Excel, but could the [information here](https://www.teachtek.com/lib/show-the-hex-color-code-format-option-in-excel/) possibly help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple . and with the help of @PaulT and my own R&D. solved

i used RGB same like instead of RGB HexCode can be replaced '0xc9f2b9'

```
ws1.Range("A" + counterC2 + ":Y" + counterC2).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(201, 242, 185);//"#c9f2b9" light green
```

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Colors : clear info here